# Field postRepository in BlogController required a bean of type 'PostRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I am writing simple Java Spring boot MVC web application.
It contains crud operations for manipulating with blog elements such as posts.

I have one error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-01 14:47:48.697 ERROR 4176 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field postRepository in com.example.demo.controllers.BlogController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repo.PostRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repo.PostRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code looks as follows, the Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.example.demo.models.Post;
import com.example.demo.repo.PostRepository;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class BlogController {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public String name(Model model, String name) {
        Iterable<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "blogmain";
    }
}
```

The repository, which is not found by Spring:

```
package com.example.demo.repo;

import com.example.demo.models.Post;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {}
```

DemoApplication.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My project structure looks [like this](https://ibb.co/BGMnwSm):

```
src/main/java/com/example/demo
|_controllers
  |_BlogController.java
  |_MainController.java
|_models
  |_[...]
|_repo
  |_PostRepository.java
|_templates
  |_[...]
|_DemoApplication.java
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are using JPA, which requires a datasource, however you excluded the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. No datasource, no JPA, no Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score -2):

In order for Spring to find your beans using "Spring Magic" you have to use the correct annotations:

Just like using `@Controller` or `@Service` for a controller or a service, there's an annotation for repositories: `@Repository`.

Annotate your repository with this.

Comment: anyway this error occurs! I have put @Repository annotation for repository

Comment: @AzizxonZufarov What about your DemoApplication? What does that look like? You might need this annotation in your DemoApplication: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo")`.

Comment: I edited question, added DemoApplication.java. The issue still occurs.

Comment: You don't need that with a spring data repository.

Comment: Seems this error does not have any solution, sorry then...